# getting meta tags info using curl and   get_meta_tags() 

Tags: php, html, curl, meta-tags

is there a way to use curl such that you can do something that is equivalent to the get_meta_tags() function in php? specifically to get the meta tags of an external site using curl in php with the least amount of overhead possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to use curl such that you can do something that is equivalent to the get_meta_tags() function in php

Nope, I don't think so.

The best way would be to fetch the data, and parse it using a [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662). Alternatively, there are several regex based approaches in the [user contributed notes in the manual.](http://www.php.net/get_meta_tags)

Comment: @Dude how does that answer use curl to parse HTML?

Comment: OP wasn't asking how to parse HTML.  The answer below uses Curl to get meta tags info. Its result is equivalent to the get_meta_tags() function in php, as asked by the OP.  Works like a dandy.

Comment: @Dude no, it uses curl to fetch the data, then goes on using a HTML parser to parse the info, as I also suggested. I agree that it's the better answer (and it probably should be the accepted one), but it doesn't make my answer *wrong*.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, though. My downvote reflects that.

Comment: @Dude the question was `is there a way to use curl such that you can do something that is equivalent to the get_meta_tags() function in php?` the correct answer is still No.

Comment: "is there a way to use curl such that you can do something that is equivalent to the get_meta_tags() function". Am I missing something here? OP was seeking a solution. The answer is below.

Comment: @Dude again: the answer below *is not using curl to extract the Metadata. It's using a HTML parsing library for that.* Curl cannot do it, it's not designed to be a HTML parser. That's why the answer is "it can't be done".

Comment: Fair enough. Arguing over the semantics of this question is benefiting nobody, however. Whatever the case I'm sure the OP finds the answer below much more useful than a black & white "No".

Comment: @Dude and you know that how? After all, the OP accepted the black & white "no" answer while they could easily have accepted the other. The question is very specifically asking for a way to do the job with *curl*, which isn't possible.

Comment: The first line of the function below looks like a call to the curl library. Am I seeing things? Lastly, It would've been impossible to accept the better answer. Your answer was accepted on the 6th if March 2011, whereas the better answer was posted 11 days later.

Comment: @Dude I'm starting to think you don't really know what the code is actually doing. Yes, it's using curl to fetch the HTML. Then it's going on to use a HTML parsing library to parse it. The OP asked whether the parsing can be done with curl, which it can't. And accepted answers can be changed, at any time. Anyway, this is a waste of time.

Comment: No need for insults, and there IS something you can do to fix this... But before I make my suggestion, allow me to say that you are an asset to this community, and it's okay to provide a less than savory answer .001% of the time. That said, please delete this answer. Delete it. Don't waste your time defending a weak answer posted 2 years ago when a much more practical solution is directly below. Google the phrase "getting meta tags using curl" and you get this page...and You, saying something to the effect of "you can't". Delete this answer, and this conversation never happened. Pretty please?

Comment: ..unless you are more concerned about being correct than you are about yielding to more practical answers...

Comment: @Dude firstly, I can't delete the answer because it's accepted. Secondly, the answer is fine. The OP didn't ask for *any* alternative to `get_meta_tags()`, but specifically a curl based one. They must have had a specific reason to ask for that - `get_meta_tags()` has been around since PHP 4, and to suggest an alternative to it, we'd have to know why the OP can't use that in the first place. The fact that they accepted the "no" answer, instead of the alternative solution, suggests that "no" told them whatever they needed to know. Why do you think you know better what was needed here?

Comment: Stackoverflow at it's best - know-it-alls correcting it wrong. Pekka's answer is completely right and answers the question perfectly. The op asked for something equivalent to php's get_meta_tags and the (very helpful) answer below is not equivalent to get_meta_tags. It's a (good) workaround in cURL to get the same result. Thanks to @Pekka 웃 and Zap to provide the correct answer AND an alternative solution!

Answer (score 10):

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.example.com");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('language') == 'language');
    $language = $meta->getAttribute('language');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```