# Meta description being returned in wrong language using php

Tags: php, html, tags, meta

I wonder if someone could shed some light on a issue i am experiencing.  I am building an SEO tool that looks at a websites title and description meta tag.  What I have experienced is that using

```
<?php

$tags = get_meta_tags("https://twitter.com");
echo $tags['description'];
?>
```

I am getting the description returned in German

> *"Verbinde Dich sofort mit den Dingen, die fÃ¼r Dich am wichtigsten sind. Folge Freunden, Experten, Lieblingsstars und aktuellen
>   Nachrichten"*

and not in English

> *"Instantly connect to what's most important to you. Follow your  friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news."*

I also discovered that Bing.com I also have this issue with too. I tried this with Curl too and got the same result.

This is what my curl code looked like,

```
<?

$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 

function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://twitter.com");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('language') == 'language');
    $language = $meta->getAttribute('language');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";

?>
```

The curl response is running here => http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/tools/4/test.php

Anyone ever come across this before?

Comment: I am in the UK and my server that I hosting on is with One.com.  I also thought this but when tested on http://web-sniffer.net/ they come up with the same problem on their website.

Comment: well you have some workarounds suggested below, but i also like to know why this happend. So you can confirm the request originating IP has no relation to austria or germany

Comment: are you able to run wireshark or tcpdump while executing the script to see what sort of request headers its sending out?

Comment: I will try run wireshark and report back

Comment: It only sends the `Host` header, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP request sent by `get_meta_tags` does not contain the traditional `Accept-Language` header that normal web browsers send in order to notify the server which language might be appropriate.

It seems like some sites (e.g. Twitter) will use a geographical IP lookup to determine the content language:

**From my local computer in Sweden**

*Koppla direkt upp dig mot det som är viktigast för dig. Följ dina vänner, experter, favoritkändisar, och nyheter.*

**From my VPS in London, UK**

*Instantly connect to what's most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favourite celebrities, and breaking news.*

So, it seems that if you intend to only look at English meta-data you would need to make your script act like an English localised web browser, using `Accept-language` and possibly other means as well.

**EDIT**: Here is an example of [how to extract the meta tags by first fetching the HTML using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917109/794003). Details on [setting the cURL headers to include `Accept-Language`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#78046).

**Code example**:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

$header = array();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://twitter.com");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('language') == 'language');
    $language = $meta->getAttribute('language');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried this with curl and got the same result => http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/tools/4/test.php , please see updated code above.

Comment: Simply using cURL is not enough, you need to combine it with the second link on how to set the `Accept-Language`header. See the code example in my updated answer.

Comment: @ChillWebDesigns The problem with your code is that $header is not set within the function. You need to add `global $header;` inside `file_get_contents_curl()` in order to access it.

Comment: Your the man, thank you so much. I tried this with Bing and Twitter and both work and return in English. In your example please update http://www.twitter.com to https://twitter.com as it didn't work with the first URL. Thanks