# get_meta_tags slow alternatives for batching

Tags: php, performance, get-meta-tags

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
echo $tags['keywords'];
```

This code is really slow for a simple page and more for 50 or more.

Is there any alternative to reacieve and URL and get the meta tags in this way?
Maybe in 2 steps or more

Thanks

Comment: Edit: file_get_contets combined gives me even worse times

Comment: The bottleneck here most likely isn't your script or it's implementation, it's I/O. If you wait on I/O, there's nothing to be done, except ..... parallelization, which, unfortunately PHP doesn't offer you solutions for.

Comment: Thanks, it seems indeed

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use curl for that.

[getting meta tags info using curl and   get_meta_tags()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151167/getting-meta-tags-info-using-curl-and-get-meta-tags)

After you get the results cache them or save to dataBase for future use.

Comment: Thanks, Already tried with curl or just file_get_contents.
Of course for future use it will improve, but I'm refering in the first run.
In the first run it is slower even using curl or file_get_contents.

Comment: You could write simple cron script and make all needed requests behind the user eyes. But don't use WP cron.